# Calling super.to_string from custom _to_string method in GDScript

Tags: gdscript, godot4

Using GDScript in Godot, I'd like to customize the string representation of a class using the default representation plus my own message. So, I'm just doing:

```
func _to_string():
    var my_string = super.to_string()
    my_string += " -> GREEN" if is_green else " -> RED"
    return my_string
```

However, this results in a stack overflow because of infinite recursion. Also tried using `(self as Object).to_string()` with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first intention was, that you need to user super() instead of super.to_string(), but this does not work either.

The docs don't say much to that either so my solution would be to instead of using the base class, mimic what it does as a default:

[here](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_object.html#class-object-method-to-string) it says the default is "<ClassName#RID>"

So your overwrite would look like this:

```
func _to_string():
    var format_string = "<%s#%s>"
    var base_response = format_string % [get_class(),get_instance_id()]
    base_response += " -> GREEN" if is_green else " -> RED"
    return my_string
```

Comment: Thanks - I was hoping to avoid that but I guess it's not too onerous. I'm still curious why this shouldn't be possible since it seems totally reasonable (at least coming from a Java programmer :) ).

Comment: I don't really understand it either. Might be worth to leave an issue in the github project.